# Управление JIT-ом

Tags: jit, java

Ну представим такую ситуацию: открыто окно программы, в нём кнопка. Программа пока отдыхает и ждёт нажатия кнопки.

В один момент юзверь нажмёт кнопку, и программе придётся исполнить метод пару тысяч(/миллионов или что-нибудь в там духе раз).

А можно сказать JIT компилятору: "Слушай, пока прога отдыхает, скомпили пожалуйста тот метод, ок?". Т.е. грубо говоря самому запустить компиляцию конкретного метода?

Comment: Вы сначала замерьте, сколько времени займет первое исполнение метода и второе (когда уже jit отработал), и тогда решайте, стоит ли овчинка выделки.

Comment: PS: зря минусанули, нормальный вопрос.

Comment: Если у людей возникают такие вопросы, то либо это сильно начинающие программисты, которые думают, что этим они ускорят как то свой код, либо те, кто просто ошибся языком программирования в самом начале.

Не нужно делать с Java чистый С. Он не для этого создавался.

Comment: Вот не правы. Вот придет к Вам заказчик, скажет: Давайте софту мне, платформа Java , а потом спросит: а чтож Ваша софтина тормозит, как хз кто?...И что Вы ему скажете, что Java не для того создавалась и надо было писать на си?:-D

Comment: если он придет именно ко мне, то я скажу, что я на java не пишу. И проблемы нет (я действительно на java не пишу, ну кроме как под андроид побаловаться).

Но обычно с заказчиком уточняют "желаемые характеристики". И всегда есть возможность сказать "так не могу/отказываюсь".


Но если софтина тормозит жутко, то тут скорее всего проблема не в java, а в том, кто код писал. и запуск прекомпиляции jit никак не поможет. Иногда замена некоторых алгоритмов на более подходящие дает громадный прирост скорости.


**главная мысль:**

не нужно путать тормоза конкретного языка/среды и тормоза программиста.

Comment: Вообще-то, если заказчик указывает программисту, на какой платформе нужно писать программу, то либо этот заказчик знает, что делает, знаком с особенностями платформы, имеет веские причины выбрать именно её и не задавать впоследствии подобных вопросов, либо он просто идиот, и в таком случае нужно слать его подальше, чтоб не мешал работать. К тому же, скорость выполнения программы в большей степени определяется программистом, её написавшим, а не платформой, особенно если платформа выбрана исходя из реальных условий, а не из пожеланий левой пятки заказчика.

Comment: @KoVadim ну тут я совсем с вами не согласен. Может ещё скажете, "что зря jit в jvm добавили — нечего из джавы си делать" :-)

UPD1 и ещё, почему вы думаете, что если кто-то хочет ускорить программу, это значит, что предидущия версия тормозит? 

Просто нужно писать быстрый код, чтоб потом не иметь дело с тормозами. И было бы круто перед некотороми методами писать @complile

Comment: не приписывайте мне то, что я не говорил, но Вы бы хотели, что бы я это сказал.

Лично мое отношение к jit - это хорошее введение, которое помогает, если не пытаться его обмануть.

Comment: я вот я лично на java (проф, в смысле по работе) тоже не писал ^_^, 
...java оч часто выступает как одно из требований к интерпрайз приложений(посмотрите ПО банков и т.п.).
а что касается тормозов, ну да jvm работает медленней, чем натив, но блин если у Вас стоит задача загрузить 10Гб трэша в оперативку, то приложение будет жрать 10Гб, вне зависимости от того на чем она написана, тормоза то в основном от нее идут(по крайней мере я еще просадки про процессору в практике не встречал)

Comment: IMHO:

1) про jit - java без него просто была бы невостребована.

2) про тормоза - память, которую безоглядно (до сборки мусора) расходуют, конечно, влияет, но кроме того, никогда не обращали внимения, что для перестановки пары байт (утрирую, само собой) вызывается десяток вложенных методов из пары пакетов. 

Ну, это сложившийся в последние лет 20 стиль программирования (проектирования), он характерен не только для Java.

Comment: ну про пару байт вопрос явно не в Java. а в том, что что-бы сделать некую операцию, отличную от стандартной (тут утрирую я), юзается либа, которая юзает либу, которая юзает либу.... т.е. по факту получается парадокс: скорее всего то что нужно написать уже написанно (редко бывают уникальные задачи) и вроде писать с нуля дорого и проблематично (разработка, тестирование, поддержка и пр), а юзать готовое даст вот такое...если я пишу diy стараюсь писать "велосипеды", на работе так незя, не оценят, получишь лишний десяток тасок в jira и еще минус пара часов личной жизни, нервы и депрессия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы уверены что не пытаетесь экономить на спичках?

Вариант решения:

1. Придумать в приложении что то
   типа [IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204577/how-to-implement-idle-task-in-java-swing) режима, и в нем
   запускать нужные методы по одному,
   до тех пор пока они не скомпилятся
   (Определить можно только косвенно).
   Точно определить скомпилировались ли
   методы нельзя - поскольку это
   происходит не сразу, а по истечении
   трешхолда.
2. Поколдовать с флагами
   (Подробнее опять на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020152/can-i-force-the-jvm-to-natively-compile-a-given-method)) и
   выставить маленький трешхолд или
   принудительную компиляцию.

У этого подхода есть куча минусов и ниодного плюса, поэтому используйте только если вы **действительно знаете**, что вам нужно компилировать методы пока процессор простаивает.

Comment: Вторая ссылка битая

Comment: поправил ссылку

Comment: > и в нем запускать нужные методы по одному, 

не нужно пытаться обмануть компилятор и jit. Он потом накажет.

Может просто в фоне запустить расчет сразу, а когда пользователь нажмет кнопку, то к этому моменту возможно все уже и рассчитано будет.

Comment: хм...забавное предложение, у него метод на дофига байтофф, который тормозит как ленивец выпивший бутыль тормозухи в спячке и его нужно вызвать кучу раз, пока ошизевший jit его не скомпилит...хм...а у Вас интересный подход к оптимизации)..уж сорри за цинизм..

Comment: Это не мой подход, я ответил на вопрос как можно в фоне JITить свою программу.

Answer (score 3):

Коротко: нет.
Развернуто: мне кажется Вы не совсем понимаете идею динамической компиляции, на то она и динамическая ;-) В смысле, что там не все так просто.
Ваша задача больше похоже на аутофтайм компиляцию.
В общем, если честно мне немного лениво расписывать идеологию, есть много хороших статей, например: [Теория и практика Java: Динамическая компиляция и измерение производительности](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp12214/)

ЗЫ: если у Вас есть место на миллион повторений, еще не факт, что именно этот код должен быть скомпилен JIT (в смысле не маловероятно, но не факи) JIT компилит все-таки байт код.